# Chips in PrimeVue are not separated correctly when assigning value to v-model

Tags: primevue

I'm using the "Chips"-Component from PrimeVue and my goal is to show something like this:

[image]

I'm using the whitespace as separator and when I enter the values manually, it works perfectly. But when I assign values to to the `v-model` values programmatically, it looks like this:

[image]

I'm using PrimeVue version 3.44 and the source of my component is the following:

```js
<template lang="pug">
Chips(v-model="test" separator=" ")
</template>

<script setup>

import { ref } from 'vue';
const test = ref('es hu')
</script>
```

Any idea what might cause the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

v-model wants an array: [See the doc here](https://primevue.org/chips/)

You have to do that:

```
const test = ref(['es','hu'])
```